# Scrollable centered NavBar

Tags: html, css

I want a navigation for my onepage which is visible while scrolling and the navigation items should be centered.

It works to center the navbar and it works that it is scrollable, but not both on the same time:

This is my nav bar:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#aa">aa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#bb">bb</a></li>
        <li><a href="#cc">cc</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS (CENTER works):

```
.nav{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}
.nav li{
    display:inline;
}
.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}
.nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

If I add:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
```

to the .nav class, the navigation is scrollable, but not centered anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with the width of your `.nav` element. So just add `width: 100%` to your `.nav` class

```
.nav{
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   text-align:center;
   width: 100%;  
   postion: fixed;
   top:0
}
```